# pre/post increment decrements evaluation in single line

Tags: c, operators, post-increment, pre-increment

can you please explain me this.

**I have read almost all questions on stackoverflow**

- 1. undefined behaviour
- 2. pre/post inc.. dec.. operator precedence/associativity
- 3. use the parenthesis

but results are inconclusive.

please explain this i have an interview tomorrow.

```
int a, x = 0;
//                               value of x ------>                 a(sum)      
//gcc 4.9.9.2[dev cpp]            2    1      2      4      5       14
//acc to my calculation           2    0      2      4      5       13      
//geeksforgeeks compiler          5    5      5      5      5       15
//gcc 6.3 [codechef ide]          5    5      5      5      5       15
a = ((((++x + x++) + ++x) + ++x) + ++x);

printf("%d....%d", x, a);

return 0;
```

if i have made mistake please help me to correct them.
Thanks

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: This can't be an interview question...

Comment: Yes, it can be an interview question. The answer will be: it''s undefined behaviour.

Comment: for some operator evaluation behavior  is not defined

Comment: *"I have read almost all questions on stackoverflow"* - That's nothing. I've seen almost all videos on Youtube. :D

Comment: but i have use the parenthesis so that there is no undefined behavior, code should work as intended.

Comment: @rewrihitesh it not related to parenthesis but to sequence points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sequence point, thus your code invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Parentheses do not introduce sequence points, thus, despite the fact that you use them, you still invoke UB.

Comment: but i have use the parenthesis so that there is no undefined behavior, code should work as intended.

Comment: @rewrihitesh: parenthesis don't introduce sequence points.

Comment: okie, thanks Mat i learned something great. Thanku again